# How to handle NaN (Not a number) in Swift correctly?

Tags: swift, crash, nan

I have a function that calculates the width of the cells for me based on a CollectionView. This layout is dynamic. In the simulator I repeated the case that the width / height of the CollectionView is NaN. How can I catch this value?

unfortunately the following solution **does not work**:

```
var collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
guard !widthCollectionView.isNaN, !widthCollectionView.isInfinite else {
  return 250
}
    
collectionViewWidth -= collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right
```

[image]

Why isn't the case caught? guard should be able to catch the value, or not?

Comment: Under what circumstances would a view width be NaN?

Comment: And where are you writing your code?

Comment: Double check that the debugger isn’t misbehaving by adding a print of the variable

Comment: I write the code normally in Xcode (latest). The error occurred if the ViewController was not in the foreground when the frame width was updated. My workaround is:
guard 0...pow(10,10) ~= collectionViewWidth else ...